# I have the map set to rotate to the users location. How do I allow the user to interact with the map?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I have the map set to center and rotate to the user's location and direction but the map view is locked, as in, I can not interact with it.

```
extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        mapView.camera.heading = newHeading.magneticHeading
        mapView.setCamera(mapView.camera, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I allow the user to explore his surroundings; scroll, zoom, interact with pins, etcetera, while centering and rotating to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method you are continually updating the map view, overriding any changes made by the user.

The solution is not to use `CLLocationManager` delegate methods to update the map view.

Simply set `userTrackingMode` on the map to `.followWithHeading` and the map view will do the work for you.  As soon as the user interacts with the map the tracking mode will change to `.none`.

You can add a button to re-activate the `.followWithHeading` user tracking mode.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense. I will try it out tomorrow. I will probably use a timer instead of a button to reactivate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up putting together and it works perfectly.

`func centerViewOnUserLocation() { mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated:true)}`